# How to make python3.7 default

Tags: python, python3

I have installed python3.7 however I am not sure how to make it the default python.

See below:

```
~/Documents/robosuite$ python3.7
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> 

~/Documents/robosuite$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I want python3.7 to show up when I use the command `python3`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Simple solution is edit `.bashrc` and put this line:

```
alias python3=python3.7
```

Whenever you will write `python3` it will replace it with `python3.7`.

Or you can use command `update-alternatives` which is preferred i.e:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
```

So here `python3.7` will have higher priority then `python3.6`.
Then use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Press the enter key if you are satisfied

Comment: **Trap for young players**: I highly recommend using update-alternatives over the alias-approach, as _aliases do not take effect in non-shell environments (also non-interactive shells ignore .bashrc)_.

Take a python-file starting with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as an example: Run with `./myscript.py` it would ignore your alias, while `python3 myscript.py` would run in python 3.7.1 in your case. Other common cases for ambiguities would be invoking commands via ssh, or from inside a shell-script.

Comment: Note that the alternatives variant above replaces `/usr/bin/python` instead of `/usr/bin/python3`, and will cause issues with Python programs which expect `python` to be Python 2 (which is the case on Debian and derivatives). See also [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) and [the Debian Python policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/python.html#base).

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 any of the two approaches caused the `No module named 'apt_pkg` error and the Terminal to not start. I wanted to use python 3.8.1 instead of  python 3.6.9.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to expand on [a previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496488/416389) as the two approaches given are not equivalent, and one of them can even break the system. The issue is there are two different things one could be trying to do by "changing the default python version".

## Quick summary

Add

```
alias python3=python3.7
```

to `.bashrc`.

Do **not** use `update-alternatives` to change your default python version, as this will break system applications.

## Further details

### Bash alias

The first, is that for an interactive shell, one simply wishes to easily open the desired python by writing

```
$ python
```

or

```
$ python3
```

This is accomplished by adding the line

```
alias python3=python3.7
```

to `.bashrc`. If one is using another shell, add this to the appropriate config file. This also has the advantage that if it causes problems for any reason, one can simply remove the offending line in `.bashrc` and restart the terminal.

### `update-alternatives`

The second thing one could mean by "changing the default python version", is to change the default python version for *all* programs, including those not launched from an interactive shell. This is the result of running

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

However, if you run this in a clean install of Debian/Ubuntu, you will notice that the command returns

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

even if you have multiple versions of python 3 installed via `apt`. There is a very good reason for this.

The problem with the this is that many system applications use python, and depending on the exact distribution, many use python 3. Changing which version is called by the command `python3` globally will force these applications to use this version. Although different version of python 3 are largely compatible, there are still [features moved and removed between releases](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#api-and-feature-removals). If a system application uses these features, changing `python3` to launch a newer version will break the application.

### Testing

I created a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM. Adding the bash alias caused no immediate issues.

Using the `update-alternatives` method caused issues with `apt`. Specifically, I got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

## Fixing your system if you ran the `update-alternatives` method

If we ran `update-alternatives` and broke `apt`, we can still fix the system. During my testing, the terminal was still able to be opened. One can go back to the default python by running

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.X 1000
```

where 3.X is your systems original python 3 version, and 1000 is just some high priority to make sure it is on top. Then, one can run

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and make sure the original system python is selected. Reboot the system and it will be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo su
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
```

... when already `python3.7` is installed

Comment: You might distinguish your answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496488/117549 , which also uses update-alternatives, to say why this is better or different.

Comment: This `update-alternatives` answer is different than the others because it aliases `python` to `python3` whereas the others were aliasing  `python3` to  `python3.X`.

Answer (score 1):

For machines which don't have the update-alternatives command, one can do a quick&dirty solution like

```
sudo ln -sf `which python3.7` `which python3`
```

Usually (at least in all cases I've seen), python3/python2/python are only symlinks to the python executable of a specific version. Changing this symlink should change the 'default python'