# How do I properly change the debian default python 2.7.9 to python3 or another version?

Tags: debian, scripting, apt, python, environment-variables

**what is best-practice for changing the default global python interpreter on my fresh debian-based linux node to python3.x?**

When I create a fresh Debian or Ubuntu VM, one of the first things I do is use `apt` to install `python3-dev` & `python3-pip`, and sometimes either `echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.bashrc` so I don't need to do it again, or even `sudo su && echo "alias python=python3" >> /etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh && exit` when I need to make a daemon user like `/home/SQLserviceacct/` or `/home/Neo4jworker/`.

The result is often havoc for potential programs or humans who make shell calls to `python` and then use any other default python-related environment variables. When things like `$PYTHONPATH` get assigned out of context, problems arise. I think `virtualenv`is probably involved somehow.

Comment: See this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496488/255251

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/a/321000/296757

Comment: Well so the first one says use `update-alternatives` which I'm starting to think might be, and the 2nd one just says to alias it like I'm already doing. I'm just wondering if there's anything more comprehensive I can do?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to link `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`, this way the change will be system wide:

`ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: I HATE PYTHON MORE THAN WORDS CAN DESCRIBE IT IS SUCH A PIECE OF **** THANKS THIS IS THE ONLY ANSWER THAT WORKS

Comment: @Anthony that's not an issue with `python`, but with your installation/system setup.